# java internationalization rules

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, compare, string-comparison

[Java Internationalization Rules](http://www.appperfect.com/support/java-coding-rules/internationalization.html#rule33). It says to replace

```
s1.compareTo(s)==0
```

with

```
Collator.compare(s1,s2)<0
```

why `<0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), it is a typo - should be `==`:

> Returns an integer value. Value is less than zero if source is less than target, value is zero if source and target are equal, value is greater than zero if source is greater than target.

This is for the `String` overload of `Collator.compare` (as the linked example compares `String`s), but [the general version of the method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#compare%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) behaves the same way.

The article you referred indirectly links to [the corresponding page of the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html), which describes the behaviour consistently with the above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should rely on this site when I see the next point ... It creates a collator returning always 0.

```
package com.rule;
public class Do_not_use_String_compareToIgnoreCase_correction
{
    public void method()
    {
        new MyCollator().compare("String", "String"); // CORRECTION
    }

    class MyCollator extends java.text.Collator
    {
        public int compare(String source, String target)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        public java.text.CollationKey getCollationKey(String source)
        {
            return null;
        }
        public int hashCode()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is just to exemplify defining a custom collator

Comment: @prongs Well even for example I won't create a method int add(int,int) with `return 2` inside because my example is `add(1,1)`. Some people just copy/paste without understanding anything